# Cucumber, java,maven,Junit extend report not generating

Tags: java, cucumber

I have tried lots of options for generating the extend report of cucumber+ java+ maven + Junit, but it is not generating the extends report. Below is my code here:

Below is my Pom.xml file:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.9.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
  <version>2.53.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
  <version>2.53.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-junit -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/info.cukes/cucumber-jvm -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
  <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.10.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.11</version>
</dependency>
<!--  Cucumber Gherkin SYNTAX -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
  <version>2.12.2</version>
 </dependency>
 <!-- 1st is for Cucumber Extent advance Reporting -->
 <dependency>
  <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
  <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
  <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
 </dependency>
 </dependencies>
 also plugins from pom.xml
 <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0</version>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0</version>
      <configuration>
        <fork>true</fork>
        <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\javac.exe</executable>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.20</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.18.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <includes>
                  <!--          <include>**/*Runner.java</include>    -->
                  <!--          <exclude>**/*Demo.java</exclude>      -->
                  <include>**/*RunnerMMT.java</include>
              </includes>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>


   TestRunner.class file
   plugin = { 
  "com.vimalselvam.cucumber.ExtentCucumberFormatter:output/report.html"
                        //"pretty","html:target/cucumber- 
   htmlreport/cucumber-pretty",
                        //"json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                        }

 @AfterClass
 public static void reportSetup()
 {
  Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new 
  File("D:\\ProjectsLive_Java\\Pls\\src\\test\\Resources\\extent- 
  config.xml"));
  /*Properties p = System.getProperties();
  p.list(System.out);*/

    Reporter.setSystemInfo("User 
     Name",System.getProperty("user.name"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", 
    System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("64 Bit", "Windows 10");
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("2.53.0", "Selenium");
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("3.3.9", "Maven");
    Reporter.setSystemInfo("1.8.0_66", "Java Version");
    Reporter.setTestRunnerOutput("Cucumber JUnit Test Runner");
 }

 extend-config.xml

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <extentreports>
 <configuration>
    <!-- report theme -->
    <!-- standard, dark -->
    <theme>standard</theme>

    <!-- document encoding -->
    <!-- defaults to UTF-8 -->
    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>

    <!-- protocol for script and stylesheets -->
    <!-- defaults to https -->
    <protocol>https</protocol>

    <!-- title of the document -->
    <documentTitle>ExtentReports</documentTitle>

    <!-- report name - displayed at top-nav -->
    <reportName>JUnit TestRunner : Cucumber Report</reportName>

    <!-- report headline - displayed at top-nav, after reportHeadline -->
    <reportHeadline></reportHeadline>

    <!-- global date format override -->
    <!-- defaults to yyyy-MM-dd -->
    <dateFormat>yyyy-MM-dd</dateFormat>

    <!-- global time format override -->
    <!-- defaults to HH:mm:ss -->
    <timeFormat>HH:mm:ss</timeFormat>

    <!-- custom javascript -->
    <scripts>
        <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function() {

    });
  ]]>
    </scripts>

    <!-- custom styles -->
    <styles>
        <![CDATA[

  ]]>
    </styles>
 </configuration>
 </extentreports>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have commented the plugin which generates the extend report and expecting it to generate the report. So my friend please undo the comment it or make changes as below.
Your test runner java file should be written something like this which will enable the extent report.

```
  import com.cucumber.listener.Reporter;
    import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
    import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
    import managers.FileReader;
    import org.junit.AfterClass;
    import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
    import java.io.File;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = ".//src//test//java//FeatureList",glue = "stepDefinations",
        plugin = { "com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/STAGE_21081018.html", // this generate the extend report
                "junit:target/cucumber-results.xml"}, // this generates the jnuit xml report.
        tags="@smoke",
        monochrome = true
)
public class TestRunner {
    @AfterClass
    public static void writeExtentReport() {
        Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File(FileReader.getInstance().getConfigReader().getReportConfigPath())); //extent-config.xml file path
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("User Name", System.getProperty("user.name"));
        Reporter.setSystemInfo("Time Zone", System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Update-

added my dependency-

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-server', version: '2.53.1'
    compileOnly 'info.cukes:cucumber-jvm-deps:1.0.5'
    compile group: 'org.testng', name: 'testng', version: '6.10'
    compile 'com.aventstack:extentreports:3.1.2'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'gherkin', version: '2.12.2'
    compile group: 'net.masterthought', name: 'cucumber-reporting', version: '3.18.0'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '1.2.5'
    testCompile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-picocontainer', version: '1.2.4'
    compile group: 'info.cukes', name: 'cucumber-java', version: '1.2.4'
    compile 'com.vimalselvam:cucumber-extentsreport:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.aventstack:extentreports:3.1.2'
    compile 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-remote-driver:2.44.0'
}
```

Comment: Hi Sobhit, Thanks for your reply, but using above combination I am not allowing to generate HTML Pretty report, jason report and Extent report. Is there any problem in above combination of dependency. it was used to working before.

Comment: @dev I am using Gradle build tool with the following dependency you can match it once. Adding my dependency list in my answer. Have a look.